# How to display multiple images at once with matplotlib in one figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, glob

I want to display multiple  images at once  in one figure (i used a set of 22 images so for the subplot i used 5 rows and 5 columns) , but the problem is they display one by one every time i close the figure, here is how i did it :

```
import cv2
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



path="data/*.jpg"

images=[cv2.imread(image) for image in glob.glob(path)]
fig=plt.figure()
for i in range(len(images)):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps you should do the final `plot.show()` outside the loop?

Comment: ,my mind went too far thinking and it was just in front of me xD , thank you

Comment: If that was the actual solution, I'll post it as the answer and get the points when you accept it\.  ;)

Comment: it is, off course you can post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are displaying the plot within the loop, and should display it after you have placed all the images.

Move `plt.show()` outside the loop.